# How to remove all vowels from the last word on every line using regex?

Tags: notepad++, regex

How to remove all vowels from the last word on every line using regex?

Example:

```
Hello world!

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Result:

```
Hello wrld!

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dg
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `[aeiou](?=[^aeiou]+$)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
[aeiou]         # a vowel
(?=             # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    [^aeiou]+       # 1 or more ay character that is not a vowel
    $               # end of line
)               # end lookahead
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

---

If you want to delete more than 1 vowel in the last word, use:

- Find what: `(?:\b|\G(?!^))[^aeiou ]*\K[aeiou]+(?=\S*$)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`

**Explanation:**

```
(?:             # non capture group
    \b              # word boundary
  |               # OR
    \G(?!^)         # restart from last match posiiton, not at the beginning of line
)               # end group
[^aeiou ]*      # 0 or more any character not a vowel or space
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
[aeiou]+        # 1 or more vowel
(?=             # positive lookahead, make sure we have, after:
    \S*             # 0 or more non space
    $               # end of line
)               # end lookahead
```